# update column using IDs

Tags: sql

Message Table

- PersonID
- EmployeeID

Employee Table

- ID
- PersonID

If the EmployeeID in Message table is correct but the PersonID are all NULL, how would I update each PersonID in the Message table to be the corresponding ID from the employee table lookup?

I'm looking for...

Message

- PersonID   NULL, NULL, NULL
- EmployeeID 1   , 2   , 3

Employee

- ID         1   , 2   , 3
- PersonID   4   , 5   , 6

TO

Message

- PersonID   4   , 5, 6
- EmployeeID 1   , 2   , 3

Answer (score 1):

You need `UPDATE` with `JOIN`. But the syntax is different for each RDBMS.

**For SQL Server:**

```
UPDATE m
SET m.PersonID = e.PersonID
FROM Message AS m
INNER JOIN Employee AS e ON m.EmployeeID = e.ID;
WHERE m.PersonID IS NULL;
```

**For MySQL:**

```
UPDATE Message AS m
INNER JOIN Employee AS e ON m.EmployeeID = e.ID;
WHERE m.PersonID IS NULL
SET m.PersonID = e.PersonID;
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard approach uses correlated subqueries:

```
update message
    set personid = (select e.personid from employees e where e.id = message.employeeid)
    where personid is null;
```